# API Direction XML and Excel Webservice function are not talking with each other

Tags: excel, xml, url, webservice-client, mapbox-api-directions

I'm tryng to analize all the distances with our clients, a good way woud be using API Directions XML. But my Websevice function in excel its not reading the XML page from API. There's any option should i able in Excel or that kind of comunication its not possible anymore?